# Pass the object other than the object on the stream to Predicate

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate, openrewrite

### Background

I am writing an OpenRewrite recipe to add some comments to the Java code. To avoid inserting the comment at unnecessary points, I have written the following code (it detects the already existing comment) and it worked properly:

```java
public class JtestSuppressDelombokVisitor extends JavaIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext> {
    @Override
    public MethodDeclaration visitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclaration methodDecl, ExecutionContext context) {
        // (snip)
        Iterator<Comment> it = methodDecl.getPrefix().getComments().iterator();
        boolean alreadyHasSuppressComment = false;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Comment comment = it.next();
            PrintOutputCapture<String> p = new PrintOutputCapture<String>("");
            comment.printComment(this.getCursor(), p);
            if (p.out.toString().matches(".*parasoft-begin-suppress\sALL.*")) {
                alreadyHasSuppressComment = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // (snip)
        return methodDecl;
    }
}
```

### Problem

I have tried to refactor the code above with the Stream API. The code needs the result of `this.getCursor()` in the process, but I couldn't find the way to pass it to the instance of `Predicate`:

```java
boolean alreadyHasSuppressComment = methodDecl.getPrefix().getComments().stream()
        .anyMatch(new Predicate<Comment>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Comment comment) {
                PrintOutputCapture<String> p = new PrintOutputCapture<String>("");
                comment.printComment(this.getCursor(), p); // <- Can't call `this.getCursor()` on the `JtestSuppressDelombokVisitor` class in the `Predicate`
                return p.out.toString().matches(".*parasoft-begin-suppress\sALL.*");
            }
        });
```

### Question

Is there any way to pass the object other than the object on the stream from outside to `Predicate`?
Or, it is impossible to write such a code with the Stream API?

Comment: Have you tried using a lambda instead of an anonymous class? I think it should properly resolve `this` from within the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the outer class because the sole `this` keyword refers to the implemented anonymous `Predicate` class.

```java
comment.printComment(JtestSuppressDelombokVisitor.this.getCursor(), p);
```

Comment: Or use a lambda expression. Which not only has the intended semantic of `this` but also needs half the code of the anonymous inner class…